# Generating / viweing XML content in bar,pie charts : Java

Tags: java

We have a Java rcp product, we need to generate results reading an xml file ie,Data source is XML file. Which tool / library I need to use to view/ populate xml data in bar,pie charts ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a crazy idea. Since you have an Eclipse RCP product you could use RCP to display a chart! There libraries such as http://www.swtchart.org which support charts in native SWT. And they are the number one hit on Google, too! And of course the good old http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart. Welcome.

Oh and the Eclipse BIRD Engine: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-BIRTChartEngine/index.html.